# losing snap config

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, lxc

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 on my windows 11 machine, every time I open my ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 I realize it lost snap configuration that I made for my lxc, lxd home lab, but the container is still saved, I'm only losing snap config so I have to run the snap command aging each time.

These are the command I have to run each time when closing, opening my ubuntu 20.04 WSL2:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig
sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME
```

Comment: Is other data saved to the container during the previous session also lost?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a bit of assumption here, but I have a hunch that the first command you list isn't really needed each startup.  If your snap container is still intact after restarting, then most likely the package installations are still there as well.

First up, try it without repeating the re-installation (the first line) and see if the second two commands (to start Systemd) still work without it.  My hunch is that they will.  If not, let me know in a comment and we'll dig further.

If lines 2 and 3 are all that are needed after a restart, then that would be completely expected behavior.  WSL doesn't automatically run any commands at startup, not even Systemd.

Several possible solutions (at least):

##### Set the commands to run at startup through shell startup and `wsl.conf`

One solution (not necessarily the right one, though), since you are running Windows 11, might be to put the `unshare` line (*without* `sudo daemonize`) into the `/etc/wsl.conf` so that it autoruns.  For other readers, note that this is not available in Windows 10, however.

`sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf`, then add the following:

```
[boot]
command="/usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target"
```

That command runs as root, so no need to use `sudo` or have to enter a password.

Then you would also need to run the `nsenter` to enter the namespace.  That needs to be done in an interactive session.  You could do it through a script that you run with the `wsl` command itself when launching, or you might add it to your `~/.bashrc`.  If you use the second technique, you'll need to check if it's already running before attempting to enter it again, otherwise you'll enter an infinite loop.  Even then, there are other problems that you need to solve, which is why I really recommend ...

##### Use an already established Systemd script for WSL2

If you are using the commands you mention in your question, then your WSL2/Ubuntu installation probably has more problems than you might realize.  If I recall correctly:

- Windows drives are probably not automatically mounted into the `/mnt/c` style directories as they normally would be under WSL2.
- Windows executables probably can't be run, since Systemd is going to wipe out the `binfmt_misc` entry that WSL sets up.
- You probably can't use GUI applications, since Systemd startup also runs `systemd-tempfiles` with a configuration that erases the WSL2 X socket (for security purposes).
- The Windows path isn't automatically appended to the Linux path, which just compounds the first two problems mentioned.

If you've already solved these, then great.  Otherwise, I'd recommend using one of the established WSL2 Systemd scripts like [Genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) or [WSL2Hacks](https://github.com/shayne/wsl2-hacks).

I don't actually run or endorse any of these personally, but if you are going to attempt to run Systemd/Snap under WSL, I'd recommend that you use one of these rather than attempting to roll-your-own.

They will also, as far as I know, also handle the autostart when launching issue.

##### An alternative process supervisor

This suggestion is (slightly) unproven from my perspective, at least on Ubuntu, but Systemd's clash with WSL's `/init` as PID 1 makes it troublesome.

You *might* find it easier to utilize an alternative process supervisor that doesn't require PID1, and then roll your own startup commands for things like D-Bus and Snapd.  One such alternative is the `supervisor` package for Ubuntu, which I have utilized successfully under Ubuntu for other similar purposes.

I'm planning on doing some more research into this personally, but I'm just not to the point where I can provide it as a full-blown solution.